# I need assistance putting this function into my html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to put this function into my html but I am not very sure how I am supposed to code the HTML help.

```
function showindialog() {
    var showoutput = "";
    showoutput += "<div id=\"result\">";
    showoutput += "    <div id=\"line\">You are " + weightclass + "<\/div>";
    showoutput += "    <p><b>BMI: <\/b>" + calculateBMI + "<\/p>";
    showoutput += "    <p><b>BMR: <\/b" + calculateBMR + "<\/p>";
    showoutput += "    <p><b>Calories to maintain weight: <\/b><br><br>" + calculateBMRwE + "<\/<p>";
    showoutput += "<\/div>";

    $("#showdialog").html(showoutput);
}
```

It should popup something in the dialog box.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script

Answer (score 1):

It will be good, if you read some documentation, learn and try to do it by yourself. Then you can post what you tried, and what issues you are facing, and people here will be happy to help. May be you can start here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/

Anyway, here is how you do it. You put code JS code inside a  tag in your html page, like so,

```html
<div id="showdialog"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function showindialog() {
      var showoutput = "", weightclass, calculateBMI, calculateBMR, calculateBMRwE;
      showoutput += "<div id=\"result\">";
      showoutput += "    <div id=\"line\">You are " + weightclass + "<\/div>";
      showoutput += "    <p><b>BMI: <\/b>" + calculateBMI + "<\/p>";
      showoutput += "    <p><b>BMR: <\/b" + calculateBMR + "<\/p>";
      showoutput += "    <p><b>Calories to maintain weight: <\/b><br><br>" + calculateBMRwE + "<\/<p>";
      showoutput += "<\/div>";

      document.querySelector("#showdialog").innerHTML = showoutput;
  }

  window.onload = function() {
    showindialog();
  }
</script>

<style type="text/css">
  #showdialog {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
  }
  #result{
    background:#ccc;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    padding: 10px;
  }
</style>
```

When you start writing more JS code it's better to keep them in a separate file and include it like so:

```
<script src="path/to/your/js/file.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```